# gdb stack trace shows no backtrace - Selected thread is running

Tags: gdb

I have a program with multiple threads. This program has been compiled with the `-g` option and has debug symbols.

```
(gdb) i threads
 Id   Target Id         Frame
  1    Thread 0x7fbb5256c9c0 (LWP 15799) "main" 0x00007fbb40dfdc93 in epoll_wait () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  2    Thread 0x7fbb149ff700 (LWP 15858) "IOService" (running)
  3   Thread 0x7fbb135ff700 (LWP 15860) "EvoAftManBt-mai" (running)
  4   Thread 0x7fbb0cfff700 (LWP 15868) "main" (running)
  5   Thread 0x7fbaecfff700 (LWP 15873) "myTimer-0" (running)
* 6   Thread 0x7fbadffff700 (LWP 15882) "stats-root" (running)>>>>>
```

What seems odd is the status at the end of each stack frame which says running...
Now if I switch to the thread I am interested in:

```
(gdb) thread 6
[Switching to thread 6 (Thread 0x7fbadffff700 (LWP 15882))](running)
(gdb) bt 
Selected thread is running
```

No backtrace is printed.

However, for the same binary if I strip off the symbols, I can see the stack trace which is baffling.

Any pointers?

Comment: Welcome at SO! Can you please add the exact compile command line (incl. all args) for the working and non-working binary + the command line with args for calling `gdb` + which commands you send to `gdb` before the shown `gdb` command (if any). THX :-)

Comment: Probably this gdb bug https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25485.